# Url routing/rewriting in asp.net 3.5 and reason to switch to asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I work in asp.net 3.5 and visual studio 2008. Do I need to switch to 4.0 and VS 2010 ? Is this very necessary ?

I want to do simple url routing in asp.net 3.5.

e.g. 
http://www.xyz.com/home     => http://www.xyz.com/home.aspx
http://www.xyz.com/contact  => http://www.xyz.com/contact.aspx .Thats all I need.

Can I do it in 3.5 easily without modifying much of web.config ? Also, do url routing results in slow speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course you can switch to Asp.NET 4.x but you dont need that if you need SEO friendly URLS.

You can do this using [ASP.NET IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for SEO-Friendly Extensionless URLs](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/bccaae4e-c90c-41a0-b2c5-cdbd3cce7d12/aspnet-iis-url-rewrite-module-20-for-seofriendly-extensionless-urls.aspx)

Asp.NET 4 requires Visual Studio 2010. Off course Asp.NET 4.x is better than 3.5 but you have to consider if you need the changes and if this justify to buy the VS2010.

**hope this helps**

Comment: Yes, it helps. Its easier than other links I have seen. But can you answer my other questions like is it a big necessity to change to 4.0. And will url writing affect loading time of page ?

Comment: Url Rewritting does off course affect your loading time. Depending on your rule how much. It looks like you doing Asp.NET WebForms, and by default, the urls are the same in 4.x. Asp.NET MVC (.NET 4) has SEO friendly urls by default. But this is not a reason to rewrite you whole application.

Comment: Actually, I am starting a new project. And dont want to switch to MVC. Just wanted to know that sticking with 3.5 is labelling me outdated or not ?

p.s. : Out of curiousty, I am going to play with json and webservices . There will be many Pagemethod function calls. Do I have better way in 4.x or MVC for such type of projects ?

Comment: I changed my answer a little bit.